# How to add an array to array field and the whole array must contain unique elements?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to carry out some as follows in MongoDB using Mongoose, is it possible?

```
const id = "5fjsjbvjbsdvjhkn6763287";
const arr = ["Hello", "World"]

await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    id,
    {
        $addToSet: {
            arrayField: arr
        }
    }
);
```

Basically, adding an array to an array field and making sure the array is of unique elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [$each](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#use-each-with-addtoset-operator) modifier is available for use with the `$addToSet` operator,

```
const id = "5fjsjbvjbsdvjhkn6763287"; 
const arr = ["Hello", "World"];
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id,
  {
    $addToSet: {
      arrayField: { $each: arr }
    }
  }
);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3VxJiyGnYIN)

Comment: Since you know the answer to my question, I have another doubt, how will I do if I have to update two array fields at once using addToSet

Comment: add another field after the first field see [playgorund](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EoKDOxkujY0)

Comment: Thanks, it worked :) Add this to the answer. Others looking for it will love it

Answer (score 2):

```js
 User.findByIdAndUpdate(id,{$addToSet: {$each: arrayObject}},{new:true}, function(err, result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("RESULT: " + result);
        res.send('Done')
    });
```

Comment: he want to keep older array element as well, `$set` will replace older elements.

Comment: and $push will push array in array it will not maintain unique element in array, look at the title of question *whole array must contain unique elements*